How can I save results from a Stepmix LCA analysis to a dataframe or a ms excel file?
I have run a Latent Class Analysis using the Stepmix package.
'model.fit(dataframe)'
gives me a perfect output in the terminal. But I need to save it to a file, preferably an Excel file after converting it to a dataframe.
'Type()'
gives me the output:
'<class 'stepmix.stepmix.StepMix'>'
I have tried pd.Dataframe() with no luck.
Anyone who can help me out here?
Kind regards

You can access model parameters as dataframes with
# Measurement parameters
mm = model.get_mm_df()

# Structural parameters
sm = model.get_sm_df()

# Class weights
cw = model.get_cw_df()

Then save them as csv with pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.

Thanks a lot, @Chu24! mm = model.get_mm_df(df) gave me exactly what I was hoping for - the model.fit(df) output into a dataframe!!
